# PHP wordpress if a text value is empty, echo

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I'm building a wordpress theme. In the backend, the user has the option to enter the url for their social networks (i.e. twitter, facebook, instagram etc). These URL's are then dynamically added to images in the theme front end linking to the respective networks.

The issue I have is that if a user doesn't enter a url for a network, I don't want the image to display. I am trying to write code that says, if the url is blank, echo 'class="hidden"' - this class has display:none in the css.

here is a snippet of my php:

```
<ul class="icons">
    <li <?php if (get_theme_mod('footer_twitter')==0) {echo 'class="hidden"'; } ?>><a href="<?php echo get_theme_mod('footer_twitter'); ?> " class="icon circle fa-twitter"><span class="label">Twitter</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

and the css:

```
ul.icons li.hidden {
   display:none;
}
```

The php code above currently outputs the echo statement for all cases, even when a url is entered in the backend. Can anyone help me with this code

Comment: `echo (empty(get_theme_mod('footer_twitter'))) ? 'class="hidden" : '';` possibly?

Comment: Afraid not. got the following fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the return of "get_theme_mod()" You can check this by using, cause i dont think it "== 0". http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_theme_mod

```
var_dump(get_theme_mod('footer_twitter'));
//string(0)
```

Here is your new code:

```
<ul class="icons">
    <li class="<?php echo empty(get_theme_mod('footer_twitter')) ? 'hidden' : ''; ?>">
        <a href="<?php echo get_theme_mod('footer_twitter'); ?> " class="icon circle fa-twitter">
            <span class="label">Twitter</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Please check this Syntax: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php its the best way to code control structures in your "View" code.

Comment: So for this to work, do I need to add the var_dump line to the top of my code?

Comment: No, var_dump just shows you the explicit return of your function "get_theme_mod()". Ensure its int(0) and not something else. Look at " get_theme_mod('footer_twitter') === 0"

Comment: Keep in mind "get_theme_mod('footer_twitter') === 0" is not the same like "get_theme_mod('footer_twitter') == 0". So, in second case, if "get_theme_mod('footer_twitter')" return bool(false) instead of int(0)  your condition is "true". cause -> "if (false == 0) { //true }" ;)

Comment: This is great, although it appears that it is not adding the class to any. Could it be because the value is a URL not an integer?

Comment: Mhmm, can you post the result of var_dump(get_theme_mod('footer_twitter')); ? Please post both, means true/false return.

Comment: string(32) "http://www.twitter.com/ceciparis" and this is the var_dump for an empty input: string(0) ""

Comment: Here you are, ensure that "get_theme_mod('footer_twitter')" return bool(false) if no url was found? :) str(0) makes no sence, when no URL was found. :) "return false".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56045/discussion-between-sam-skirrow-and-lin).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if (!empty (get_theme_mod( 'set_address2' ))) {
    echo get_theme_mod( 'set_address2');
}?>
```

This seemed to work for me in Wordpress.
Let me know if this works.

Comment: I just saw how long ago this question was asked.  I hope I'm not too late.